# Como fazer o .load do jQuery carregar apenas o conteúdo dentro do <main>?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Como poderia fazer para que a função `.load` ao invés de carregar o conteúdo do `<body>` carregue apenas o conteúdo dentro de `<main>` ?

Meu jQuery:

```
// Checa se a página foi carregada para evitar aplicar os códigos antes de ter algum elemento não carregado. Pode-se usar também "$(function(){".
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".ajax").on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); //eliminamos o evento
                var path = $(this).attr("href"); //Pegamos o caminho
                var titulo = $(this).data('titulo'); //pegamos o titulo da página
                document.title = titulo; // Alterar o titulo da página
                window.history.pushState("", titulo, path);   
                $("main").empty(); //Limpa para poder colocar o conteúdo.
                $("main").load(path); //Faz uma requisição http para o servidor.
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <!-- No caso, o header é a parte fixa, que não muda. -->
    <header>
        <div>"Aqui fica o player de audio."</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html" class="ajax" data-titulo="Início do meu Site">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="sobre.html" class="ajax" data-titulo="Sobre mim">Sobre</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <main>
        <!-- Aqui é onde o conteúdo vai ser carregado. -->
    </main>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta colocar o elemento que deseja carregar após a URL separado com um espaço, como no ex. abaixo:

```
$(".ajax").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //eliminamos o evento
    var path = $(this).attr("href"); //Pegamos o caminho
    var titulo = $(this).data('titulo'); //pegamos o titulo da página
    document.title = titulo; // Alterar o titulo da página
    window.history.pushState("", titulo, path);   
    $("main").load(path + ' main', function () {
        $("main").html($(this).children('main').html());
    }); //Faz uma requisição http para o servidor.
});
```

Note que ao carregar com o load um elemento dentro dele mesmo, vai ocorrer o aninhamento um dentro do outro:

```
<main>
<main>
conteúdo...
</main>
</main>
```

que pode causar problemas de visualização ou outros bugs indesejáveis..
Então tive que fazer aquela função no complete do load, para desaninhar os elementos.

Outra solução que costumo usar para facilitar essa questão é criar um elemento container/receptor (que deve estar em todas as paginas) assim:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ajax-container">
<main>
conteúdo...
</main>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
...
$("#ajax-container").load(path + ' main');
...
```

Comment: Olá @Jader eu me ausentei ontem o dia todo. Vou testar seu exemplo. Acredito que vai dar certo, porque acho que o problema é nesse (path) mesmo. :D

Comment: Funcionou! Vlw Jader, de novo solucionando meus problemas, rsrs...

Comment: Veja: http://player.esy.es/novo/

Answer (score 1):

no HTML coloque:

```
   <body>
    <!-- No caso, o header é a parte fixa, que não muda. -->
    <header>
        <div>"Aqui fica o player de audio."</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html" id="ajax" data-titulo="Início do meu Site">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="sobre.html" id="ajax" data-titulo="Sobre mim">Sobre</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <main id="conteudo">
        <!-- Aqui é onde o conteúdo vai ser carregado. -->
    </main>


</body>
```

No jQuery faça o `load()` assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("a#ajax").on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); //eliminamos o evento
                var path = $(this).attr("href"); //Pegamos o caminho
                var titulo = $(this).attr('data-titulo'); //pegamos o titulo da página
                document.title = titulo; // Alterar o titulo da página
                window.history.pushState("", titulo, path);   
                $("#conteudo").empty(''); //Limpa para poder colocar o conteúdo.
                $("#conteudo").load(path); //Faz uma requisição http para o servidor.

                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar!

Comment: Não funcionou!.

Comment: Dei uma editada. Faça o teste.

Comment: Continua. O erro persiste.

Comment: Qual erro que está dando?

Comment: É que o que você está fazendo é colocando o id do elemento onde é para aparecer o conteúdo carregado. O que eu quero é que o `.load` que carregue só o que estiver dentro do elemento com `ID`.